# order html table rows with value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I want to ordering table with total of marks

row 1: `354`
row 2: `328`
row 3: `317`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a free code-writing service; we help you with *your* code. Try something, then come back if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to sort the table in a descending manner, by Total:</p>
  <p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Subject 1</th>
      <th>Subject 2</th>
      <th>Subject 3</th>
      <th>Subject 4</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Student 1</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>95</td>
      <td>317</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Student 1</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>95</td>
      <td>328</td>
    </tr>



  </table>

  <script>
    function sortTable() {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      switching = true;
      /*Make a loop that will continue until
      no switching has been done:*/
      while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          //start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
          one from current row and one from the next:*/
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];
          //check if the two rows should switch place:
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done:*/
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

> Please use this for sorting the table. You can change the order (ascending / descending) by changing the condition in the if case.